# YUI 2 Populate Select with JSON

Tags: javascript, yui

Really simple question but I can't find an answer. I know how to do this in regular javascript and I know how to do this in jquery. Right now if I have this:

```
var states = [{"name":"alaska","id":1},{"name":"alabama","id":2];
```

Is there an YUI based method to push that into a select box, to set the selected item, to get the selected item back? If so, where's the online example? If not I'll just use javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can do something like this:

```
var buttonMenu = [

        { text: "Alaska", value: 1, onclick: { fn: onStateClick } },
        { text: "Alabama", value: 2, onclick: { fn: onStateClick } },
        ...];
```

.. and then use this in a YUI menu button configuration:

```
var statesButton = new YAHOO.widget.Button({ type: "menu", label: "Alabama", name: "mymenubutton", menu: buttonMenu, container: containerElement });
```

More details on the [YUI button example page](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/button/btn_example07.html).
Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice! Does it have to be a button? Can you do the same thing to a regular <select> item?

Comment: Hmm. Well, not with YUI, I think. You can either skin your own select or you should write your custom javascript then to automatically build the select button. Which could also be done with YUI :) But check the link - you can do a lot of Button config if something isn't the way you need it.